# Cerrar un proceso recientemente abierto C#

Tags: c#, excepciones, consola, timer, proceso

Estoy necesitando realizar la ejecución de un proceso por un tiempo determinado, para lo que inicio un proceso, y mediante un `Timer` tras 10 minutos, lo mato usando `Kill()`, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
public class Manager{
    private Process Proceso;

    public Manager(){        
        //Inicio el proceso EdmServer
        Proceso = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS PDM\EdmServer.exe");
        //StopProcess se ejecuta tras 10 minutos.
        Timer t = new Timer(StopProcess, null, 600000 , 0);
    }

    private void StopProcess(object o)
    {
        try
        {             
            Proceso.Kill();
        }    
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.CreateLog();
        }
        finally
        { 
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

El código funciona como espero, el asunto, es que al elevar el tiempo que pretendo mantener el proceso abierto, incrementando la espera del `Timer`, al momento de cerrar el proceso, se genera la siguiente excepción:

> No se puede procesar la solicitud porque el proceso ha terminado.

El asunto es, que pasa por el `finally`, termina la ejecución, pero el proceso que pretendo cerrar sigue abierto.

¿Porque se lanza la excepción si el proceso NO terminó?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según veo en el código suministrado en su pregunta, no está especificando cuál es el proceso a terminar.

Para terminar el proceso correctamente puede usar el siguiente código:

```
Process [] proc Process.GetProcessesByName("EdmServer.exe");
proc[0].Kill();
```

> Código modificado de: [How to terminate a process in c# - social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/50ecbcf2-d2d3-4f21-9775-5b8be1bd4346/how-to-terminate-a-process-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

También vale la pena tener en cuenta la información disponible en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.7.2):

- El método "Kill" se ejecuta asíncronamente. Después de llamar al método "Kill", llame al método [WaitForExit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2) para esperar a que el proceso salga, o revise la propiedad [HasExited](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=netframework-4.7.2) para determinar si el proceso ha salido.
- [NotSupportedException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=netframework-4.7.2): Generado al llamar al método `Kill()` para un proceso que está corriendo en un computador remoto. El método `Kill()` solo está disponible para procesos corriendo en el computador local.
- Si el llamado al método `Kill` es realizado mientras el proceso está terminando, la excepción [Win32Exception](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=netframework-4.7.2) es lanzada indicando (Acceso Denegado).

Answer (score 0):

Para terminar un proceso en especifico utilizar la siguiente linea de codigo.

```
Process[] proc =  Process.GetProcessesByName("Programa.exe");
        proc[0].Kill();
```